# Sumar campos en yii2

Tags: yii2

Esta es mi primera consulta en este sistema, la consulta es sobre **`yii2`**, espero me puedan apoyar.

Necesito saber cómo sumar una columna de la base de datos y mostrarla en ***footer*** del ***GridView***.

Se cómo se hace en **`Mysql`**:

```
SELECT SUM(precio) AS totalprecio FROM productos
```

Pero no sé cómo hacerlo con **`yii2`** y mostrarlo en la vista.

@MauricioJavierBiott.
Agrego el controlador y la vista, como solicitas.
Controlador.

```
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        if (Yii::$app->user->identity->rol_id == 1)
        {
            $searchModel = new DeudoresSearch(['users_id' => Yii::$app->user->id]);
            $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

            return $this->render('index', [
                'searchModel' => $searchModel,
                'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            ]);
        }
        else
        {
            return $this->render('@app/views/partials/_denegado');
        }
    }

View index
<?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        // 'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

            // 'id',
            // 'users_id',
            'unidad_id',
            'torre',
            'mes',
            'year',
            'interes',
            'multas',
            'gastocomun',
            [
                'attribute'     => 'estado_id',
                'value' => function($model) {
                    $estado = Estados::findOne($model->estado_id);
                    return $estado->estado;
                },
                'filter' => ArrayHelper::map(Estados::find()->all(), 'id', 'estado'),
            ],
            //'nota:ntext',
            //'created_at',
            //'updated_at',
            //'created_by',
            //'updated_by',

            // ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ],
    ]); 
    ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

el GridView de yii2 te deja  sumarizar sin la necesidad de recurrir a un select sum().  Por ejemplo:

```
<?= \yii\grid\GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'showFooter' => true,
    'columns' => [
        ['attribute' => 'precio',
            'footer' => sumarizeFooter( $dataProvider->getModels() ),
            'format' => 'raw',
        ],
    ]
]) ?>
```

Y por otro lado en el view puedes definir la funcion sumarizeFooter()

```
function sumarizeFooter($model){
    $iSum = 0;
    foreach ($model as  $obj){
        $iSum += floatval($obj->precio);
    }
    return $iSum;
}
```

En el caso que muestras en tu código solo deberías modificar el view para que haga la suma del campo que deseas. Por ejemplo gastocomun.

Te quedaría asi :

```
<?php
function sumarizaGastocomun($dataProvider){
    $suma = 0;
    foreach ($dataProvider->getModels() as $itm){
        $suma += $itm->gastocomun;
    }
    return $suma;
}
?>

<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    // 'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'showFooter' => true,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
        // 'id',
        // 'users_id',
        'unidad_id',
        'torre',
        'mes',
        'year',
        'interes',
        'multas',
        [
            'attribute' =>'gastocomun',
            'footerOptions' => [ 'style' => 'color:red'],
            'footer' => sumarizaGastocomun($dataProvider)
        ],
        [
            'attribute' => 'estado_id',
            'value' => function($model) {
                $estado = Estados::findOne($model->estado_id); return $estado->estado;
            },
            'filter' => ArrayHelper::map(Estados::find()->all(), 'id', 'estado'), ],
        //'nota:ntext',
        //'created_at',
        //'updated_at',
        //'created_by',
        //'updated_by',
        // ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],
]);
?>
```

Espero te sea útil.

Comment: No tienes que hacer sum  porque el sumarizeFooter recorre todo el $dataProvider .. y suma el attribute que quieres sumar.

Comment: Estas utilizando un dataProvider en el GridView ?

Comment: Si editas mostrando como tienes el controller y el view con el GridView quizas pueda darte una mano con el tema.

Comment: edite y agregue el controlador y la vista, Gracias

Comment: El attributo precio no se encuentra en el gridview ?

Comment: No, ese solo lo puse como ejemplo, el atributo es gastocomun

Comment: Edite con el ejemplo completo de como debría quedar el view

Comment: Error
Call to undefined function sumarizeFooter() si pongo footer' => sumarizeGastocomun($dataProvider) no da error, pero no muestra en ninguna parte la suma, o tengo que poner algo mas?

Comment: Perdón debes reemplazar sumarizeFooter por sumarizaGastocomun . Ahi lo edité . Debe aparecer al final del gridview en rojo

Comment: Si ya lo hice, pero no muestra la suma, que puede ser?

Comment: Agregaste 'showFooter' => true, ?

Comment: Ahora lo agregué y ahí funcionó, muchas Gracias

Comment: Me alegro que haya resultado.

Comment: No olvides de marcar la respuesta como correcta para el resto de la comunidad

Comment: Perdón, como hago eso

Comment: Aqui tienes un explicativo https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427/c%C3%B3mo-funciona-la-aceptaci%C3%B3n-de-respuestas

Comment: ERROR: La propiedad "CGridView"."showFooter" no se encuentra definida.